# Upgrades don't reset when times reach zero

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm newbie with php and wordpress. I purchase a theme where users can purchase 3 different upgrades to their profile.
Problems is that when times reach zero upgrades do not reset.

This code is what I think that "start" the upgrades after purchase:

```
case "package_process_upgrade": {
    
        $type = $order_data[0];
        $pid = $order_data[1];
     
        switch($type){              
            case "sponsored": {
                update_post_meta($pid, 'sponsored', 1); 
                
                // ADD ON TIMER
                if(is_numeric(_ppt(array('lst', 'addon_sponsored_days'))) && _ppt(array('lst', 'addon_sponsored_days')) > 0){
                update_post_meta($pid, 'sponsored_expires', date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( current_time( 'mysql' ) . " +"._ppt(array('lst', 'addon_sponsored_days'))." days")) ); 
                }
                
            } break;
            case "homepage": {
                update_post_meta($pid, 'homepage', 1); 
                
                // ADD ON TIMER
                if(is_numeric(_ppt(array('lst', 'addon_homepage_days'))) && _ppt(array('lst', 'addon_homepage_days')) > 0){
                update_post_meta($pid, 'homepage_expires', date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( current_time( 'mysql' ) . " +"._ppt(array('lst', 'addon_homepage_days'))." days")) ); 
                }
                
            } break;
            case "featured": {
                update_post_meta($pid, 'featured', 1); 
                
                // ADD ON TIMER
                if(is_numeric(_ppt(array('lst', 'addon_featured_days'))) && _ppt(array('lst', 'addon_featured_days')) > 0){
                update_post_meta($pid, 'featured_expires', date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( current_time( 'mysql' ) . " +"._ppt(array('lst', 'addon_featured_days'))." days")) ); 
                }
            } break;
        }
    } break;
```

What I think is that is missing a function that loop and check that time is zero and reset custom fields from 1 to 0.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: I try to explain what I need.

Comment: Example for sponsored:
I have 2 custom fields that are created when I purchase upgrade sponsored.
Custom fields are:
Name: sponsored - Value: 1
Name:sponsored_expires - Value(date): 2022-xx-xx xx:xx:xx
Problem is when upgrade expires and time reach zero do not reset upgrade and custom fields values doesn't change.
I'm looking for a function that when time is zero transform:
Name: sponsored - Value: 0
Or (maybe better) delete both custom fields when time reach zero.
And where to place this function ( function.php or the same file that is wrote the code )